# Amazon Cost Explorer: Costs with "no resource" in Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services

Suppose i am using Amazon Lightsail and i have costs which is showing "no resource". I know, that they are caused by Lightsail, but how am i able to find out, what entity is exactly causing this costs without waiting for the billing report?

Comment: Let's not "suppose." Edit your question with the _exact_ information that want to discover. Put in screenshots of your Cost Explorer report if necessary.

Comment: I just want to see, what is causing my costs. Is there any way? This is not a hard problem.

Comment: No, it's not a hard problem. I'm sure that there are a lot of people who could answer it right away if you provided actual information rather than paraphrasing what you see. But since you're unwilling to do that, it becomes not just hard but impossible.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could also look at your current month billing detail, which breaks down costs by categories and is updated at least once a day.